# Changing user folder location on install for Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I know that I can change the path of the User folders in Windows 10 to not be located on the C:. My question is, is there a way to do this during the install? Is it possible/safe to do the same with the AppData folders?

Comment: Use `Sysprep` as described in [How to Move Users Folder to another Location in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score -1):

After installation of Windows, we can configure [Folder redirection](https://4sysops.com/archives/folder-redirection-part-4-group-policy-configuration/) for some user data and configure Prevent use of Offline Files to make sure that these files are saved online ( User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Network > Offline Files.)